# How to use vue-axios in Vue3 Composition API?

Tags: express, axios, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm using `express` with NodeJS for running the APIs
For Authentication I'm using the below package

```
const session = require('client-sessions');

app.use(session({
cookieName: 'session',
secret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET,
duration: 30 * 60 * 1000 * 30,
activeDuration: 60 * 60 * 1000 * 30
}));
```

I'm using express
I have imported `axios` and `VueAxios` in my `main.js` file with the below code:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import './assets/style.css'
import router from './router'
import axios from 'axios';
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(VueAxios, axios, router)
app.provide('axios', axios)
app.provide('VueAxios', VueAxios)
app.mount('#app')
```

Here is the code in my Component Javascript Block

```
import { onBeforeMount, onMounted, ref, inject } from "vue";

setup() {

    const axios = inject('axios');
    const VueAxios = inject('VueAxios');

    onMounted(async ()=> {
         
        VueAxios.axios.get(...... // I get this error - Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

        VueAxios.get(...... // I get this error - VueAxios.get is not a function

                    
        axios.get(......  // this works, but how do I use VueAxios for passing session payload? 
    })


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the below line of code after `app.provide('VueAxios', VueAxios)` made it work

```
 axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```